# Path integral and least action principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, path-integral, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I'm reading Sakurai's book. And there is a part, where it says: let's consider the path that satisfies 
$$\delta S(N,1) = 0,$$
where the change in $S$ is due to a slight deformation of the path with fixed ends.
$$S(n,n - 1) = \int_{{t_{n - 1}}}^{{t_n}} {dt{L_{classical}}(x,\dot x)}.$$
Then it asserts that such a path is denoted by $S_{min}$ and if we deform the path a little bit from the classical path the resulting path is still equal to $S_{min}$ to the $1^{st}$ order of deformation. But how is it possible? Isn't $S_{min}$ unique according to calulus of variations given that the ends are fixed?

Comment: "if we deform the path a little bit from the classical path the resulting path is still equal to  to the 1 order of deformation." This simply means that the (functional) derivative is 0, which is the definition of an extremum. Could you elaborate more on the problem you see there?

Comment: I suppose that there is the only path satisfying that minimum condition and if we deform it then the condition won't be met. Do I have bad understaning of variational calculus?

Comment: First of all, it's not the minimal condition but the extremal condition. Paths satisfying it will be lokal minima or maxima. And yes, if you deform an extremal path up to first order $S$ wont change, however, there might be changes in second or higher orders. Imagine what happens if you vary a parameter $x$ in $f(x)=x^2$ around $x=0$. Up to first order $\delta f = 0$, still, you only have one minimum.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much

Comment: Have a look at Feynman's chapter on least action principle. It's in its volume 2. It will surely help you

Comment: I will, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $q:[t_i,t_f]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a [stationary path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) for the action functional $S$, then by definition, the variational/[functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) 
   $$\frac{\delta S[q]}{\delta q(t)}~=~0\tag{1}$$
   vanishes at the stationary path $q$.
2. Let us Taylor-expand the action functional around the stationary path:
   $$S[q+\delta q] ~=~S[q]
   ~+~\int_{[t_i,t_f]} \! \mathrm{d}t \underbrace{\frac{\delta S[q]}{\delta q(t)}}_{=0}\delta q(t)
   ~+~\frac{1}{2}\iint_{[t_i,t_f]^2} \! \mathrm{d}t~\mathrm{d}t^{\prime} \frac{\delta^2 S[q]}{\delta q(t)\delta q(t^{\prime})}\delta q(t)\delta q(t^{\prime})
   ~+~{\cal O}((\delta q)^3). \tag{2}$$
3. In our notation the quote of Sakurai on p. 119 below eq. (2.5.39) becomes:

   > *We now attempt to deform the path a little bit from the stationary path $q:[t_i,t_f]\to \mathbb{R}$. The resulting $S[q+\delta q]$ is still equal to S[q] to first order in deformation.*

Comment: I do not understand why this answer was downvoted. This answer is correct.